# Regular expression for removing particular HTML tags

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in Java to remove all from start of `<select>` and end of select `</>` tag as shown below. I wrote a regular expression to remove everything starting from `<start>` tag with empty as below. The issue is it's removing everything as expected except in the fourth line, `<select name="first" ... the popular`. It removes everything in that line and ignores content which is in the next line, `and ... president"/>`. I want to include everything from start and end tag. How can I do that?

```
str.replaceAll(".*<start.*", "");
```

The actual String str has content shown below:

```html
<select name="id" content="2454803.html"/>
<select name="nameid" content="2454803"/>
<select name="type" content="prd"/>
<select name="first" content="In 2004, Charlie, the popular 
and charismatic senator , became the first president"/>
<select name="title" content="Charlie"/>
<h1>
<!--toc:insert content="checkbox" id="_1_0"/>-->
</h1>
<p class="tocline"><a href="2454803">Table of Contents</a></p>
```

Comment: You should use an HTML parser to do that kind of stuff

Comment: there should be a filter that just redirects you to [why this won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) when you put `regex` and `html/xml` in the title! That and we need a *"close because this is about parsing html with regular expressions"*

Comment: @fge this is not the html as such . Iam treating this whole html as one string content.

Comment: Even though, this doesn't prevent the fact that what is in the string is HTML and that an HTML parser remains the best tool. Same for JSON: you don't use regexes to manipulate JSON but a JSON parser.

Comment: If one of the answers here satisfactorily solves your problem, please accept is by clicking the checkmark next to it. If you can't decide which to accept, you may find this useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers

Answer (score 3):

According to the Java documentation, at [Pattern.html#lt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt):

> The regular expression`.`matches any character except a line terminator unless the[`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)flag is specified.

A line terminator meaning:

> - A newline (line feed) character (`'\n'`),
> - A carriage-return character followed immediately by a newline character (`"\r\n"`),
> - A standalone carriage-return character (`'\r'`),
> - A next-line character (`'\u0085'`),
> - A line-separator character (`'\u2028'`), or
> - A paragraph-separator character (`'\u2029`).

The easiest way to specify the [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag is by adding `(?s)` to the beginning of the regex. There also need to be a few more changes to accommodate this flag, so the final regex would be `(?s)<select.*?>\r?\n?`, applied like

```
str.replaceAll("(?s)<select.*?>\\r?\\n?", "");
```

Demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/bW8aR7

Alternatively, you could use the regex `<select[^>]*>\r?\n?`, like this:

```
str.replaceAll("<select[^>]*>\\r?\\n?", "");
```

Demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/lO6mQ6

Comment: i tried with str.replaceAll("(?s)<select.*?>\\r?\\n?", "") as mentioned above and it worked for me.

Comment: Given link is good to try and find the right Regex and then use it in code.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments mentioned, you really shouldn't use regex for this. However, the issue is that the dot character in regex doesn't match newlines by default. You have to include (?s) at the start of the regex to make it do so. So:

```
str.replaceAll("(?s)<select.*?/>", "");
```

Comment: Uhm, this will pretty much replace _every input_ where there is `<select` in it with nothing...

Comment: Hmm, didn't look at that one very closely. I just threw on the dot matches newline assuming his regex was correct besides that. Fixed.

Comment: First, the `*` needs to be made non-greedy with `?` or else it will start matching `<select` and continue until the very last instance of `/>`.  This isn't an issue in the example in the question, but it would be a problem in any code that has `/>` at some later point.  Second, it's a bit more straightforward to just use a set of character classes along with its negated class to match `.` and newline characters instead of adding modifiers to the beginning of the expression.  Here's what I would do: `.*<select[\s\S]*?/>`

Comment: i tried this above regex and it worked for me. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're statement is

```
str.replaceAll(".*<select.*", "");
```

not

```
str.replaceAll(".*<start.*", "");
```

You need to ignore everything before and after the `<select`

something like this will grab the tag names (anything after the `<`

```
(?<=\<)start(?=(.*))
```

or you could grab `<start` with

```
(?<=.)\<start(?=(.*))
```